# Visual Studio 2012 - Intellisense shows but no summary description

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, intellisense, mscorlib

In the image, the top is what I see when using target framework v3.5.

However, if I switch to any other framework, e.g. v3.5 Client Profile, then the descriptions are available again.

[image: Intellisense - No Summary Descriptions]

I've isolated the problem down to the reference to the mscorlib.dll.  I right click on a `String` and then choose `Go To Definition F12`.

When I use v3.5, it references from `C:\Windows`, and the dll doesn't contain any comments or descriptions, which makes sense why intellisense doesn't display any.

```
#region Assembly mscorlib.dll, v2.0.0.0
// C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll
#endregion
```

When I use v3.5 Client Profile (or any other, e.g. v4.0, v4.5), it references from `C:\Program Files (x86)\` and descriptions start working again (even without restarting Visual Studio).

```
#region Assembly mscorlib.dll, v2.0.0.0
// C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v3.5\Profile\Client\mscorlib.dll
#endregion
```

Can someone please confirm if they use target framework v3.5 and go to definition on a String, what is the path to the mscorlib.dll?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix my problem. The last step I did before it was fixed was to go to `Control Panel -> Programs -> Programs & Features`, then click on `Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 Multi-Targeting Pack` and click on `Repair` (it should appear in the table header after clicking on it.

The strange thing is that it is still referencing the same DLLs as before when the comments weren't showing up:
`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll`
The date stamp on the dll hasn't changed.

I tried some other things that may have contributed:

`Control Panel -> Programs -> Turn Windows features on or off`
I unchecked, clicked `OK`, and then rebooted, and then rechecked.

I reinstalled the `dotnetfx35setup.exe` download from Microsoft.

I tried copying the files
from:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\`
to:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v3.5\`

However, this only gave a partial list of DLLs and at once point Visual Studio was complaining about core DLLs missing. As well, if I undid the move, and went to `References -> Add Reference...` then Visual Studio would show the window but the table that normally lists out the available DLLs would say 'no framework assemblies were found on the machine'.

I also tried repairing the visual studio installation. This took a long time and the problem was not fixed.

Here is another thread with a the same problem that talks about copying the files:
[Missing documentation for system-assemblies in VS2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22028236/missing-documentation-for-system-assemblies-in-vs2012)

Comment: Thanks for this, VS2015 doesn't have intellisence for .net 4.6, so knowing your solution helped me fix things (unfortunately it was downgrading to 4.5.2)