# Visual Studio 2015 missing XML comments / documentation

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2015, xml-comments

Is it me or are the XML comments missing for `System.Linq` in *Visual Studio 2015*?
Because I can still find it on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
But when typing, for example, this code:

```
var list = new List<string>();
list.Select(
```

IntelliSense doesn't provide the comments/documentation for *any* class/method/member/extension in the `System.Linq` namespace:
[image]

Here is a preview when hitting (**Alt** + )**F12** to *go to definition* for a random extension method on `Enumerable`:
[image]
I think I didn't notice the docs in Visual Studio 2013 either. But I do remember them being there once upon a time, perhaps that was in Visual Studio 2012 or before?

**EDIT**: I've forgot to mention that I've Resharper 10 Ultimate installed in Visual Studio 2015. I've also had Resharper 8 and 9 installed in Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I recently upgraded to VS15 & and am having a similar issue. For me, more than just Linq docs are missing. Most of the xml comments for Dictionary<T,K> are missing for example. I tried to find a more complete version of .Net 4.6.1 as suggested by spellizari, repaired the installation and re-installed completely, but neither worked.

Comment: I was going to try *spellizzari's* solution, and if that worked mark it as an answer. But since you've tried it without success, I'm guessing it won't work. I'll try it anyways soon whenever I have the time. But until now, no, I've never found a solution. I've forgot to mention that I have Resharper installed, perhaps this might be the issue? Do you have Resharper installed?

Comment: I have the same issue using VS2015 and Resharper 10. For the moment I've reinstalled Resharper 9.2 and every thing work fine.

Comment: I haven't found a solution yet to my problem yet, but I think that our two issues may be partially different. I think my issue may be caused by a bug (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7e44b54c-3b3b-444f-9e3a-470b54a480ce/framework-46-why-is-the-xml-documentation-missing-important-types?forum=netfxbcl). Since my post yesterday, I have completely uninstalled VS15 & all versions of .Net & associated SDKs. On reinstall of VS15, however, the issue persists. @spellizzari's solution does give a good hint @ the location of the xml doc files at least. Perhaps check there for clues

Comment: Also see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22028236/missing-documentation-for-system-assemblies-in-vs2012

Comment: After giving @spellizzari's solution, I believe this could work. It seems that installing VS15 only installs .NET 4.5 Multi-Targeting Pack and not the .NET 4.5 Multi-Targeting Pack (ENU). It does install the regular AND ENU versions for 4.5.1 and up, however. Now I just need to figure out where to find an installer for 4.5 ENU.

Comment: In my case the XML docs are not missing.. But inside the xml docs for the System.Linq namespace in `System.Core.xml` I can't seem to find the documentation for those extension methods for the static class `Enumerable`.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem but for a whole framework (4.6). In fact, I missed all the XML files for the whole Framework assemblies in the folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6".

The problem was that I installed the *Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6 Targeting Pack* that I got from the MSDN download center, but I missed the other smaller msi package that got along. The main package only installs the necessary assemblies, and you have to install the other one (ENU, ITA, etc.) to get those XML files in the language chosen on the download page.

Comment: The weird thing for me is that, when I take a look at the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v*` directories, I can see a bunch of XML docs sitting there aside their sibling dll's. Now the odd thing is, in my case it was only for `System.Linq` which comes from `System.Core.dll`. When I take a look inside `System.Core.xml`, and *Ctrl+F* to one of those extension methods, I get no result.. So I'm really guessing that Microsoft introduced a bug somewhere along.

Answer (score 1):

**The xml comments / documentation isn't broken but your intellisense is.**

Go to definition for external types will only show you a version from metadata of the source code.

Which is why you get this at the the top:

```
#region Assembly System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
// C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.Core.dll
#endregion
```

And it says `[from metadata]`:

[image]

I see the same going to definition on `Select`, but I do get more intellisense than in your screenshot:

[image]

Comment: So the question then remains, how can I fix this? Because the docs are only missing for me in the `System.Linq` namespace. All other .NET namespaces have the docs. I don't think my IntelliSense is broken, but that this specific assembly is broken. Don't you think? Otherwise IntelliSense wouldn't show me docs for other namespaces.

Comment: You see the comments in the metadata (the ... in front of each member) while @QuantumHive does not have them in the metadata.

Answer (score 0):

I still have this problem after a fresh install of visual studio 2019...
The solution is to manually download the SDK ( .Net framework Developer Pack) [from Microsoft](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework).